# RxDB leader-ship blocks all sockets in chrome

Tags: javascript, rxdb

I used the `waitForLeadership` to let only one tab sync the db. And it looks like it works. But if I activate this feature and open more than 3 tabs, the next tabs won't load. 
Chrome always says, `waiting for available socket...`

Did anyone had/have the same issue?

What did I do wrong? Did I have to manually start the sync process? If I insert in one instance, master or not, it is visible in all correctly. But it seems, that multiple instances try to open a socket/long polling.

```
newRxDb.waitForLeadership().then(() => {
   console.log(`isLeader now`);
});
```

Comment: I also asked on [github](https://github.com/pubkey/rxdb/issues/1916)

Answer (score 1):

I think there's some issue in your service worker no problem, this issue may have been resolved by the release of rxdb v 9.0.0

But I think the problem may be that you are opening multiple browser consoles for the same url, so you can try to check for leadership directly in your *title*

Whichever page is leader will be prefixed as Online along with the title name

```
    // show who's the leader in page's title
    db.waitForLeadership().then(() => {
      document.title = 'Online ' + document.title;
    });
```

This is just my opinion, hope this helps